# Releasing a CTFont object completely?

Tags: memory-management, core-text

Whenever I first create a **CTFont** object it consumes about 10 MB of real memory.

```
 CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica"), fontSize, NULL);
 CFRelease(font);
```

After calling **CFRelease** the memory consumption doesn't change so I'm assuming that some sort of font cache is built and stored. *How can I make it consume less memory?*

I am concerned because the rest of my application which does a lot of things only weighs 2 MB and the little bit that produces text output takes up 5 times as much. And *no*, I can't use other text output methods.

Comment: is it 10mb or 10kb. I use the same function but it uses only 10kb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should bother about this issue. Calling `CFRelease` is pretty-much okay and about what you can do. 10MB is not too much. If you have this problem, probably all CoreText apps have it. You could file a bug for it and see what they respond. Maybe it loads the whole font database that is then cached somewhere for better performance. I think there's nothing you can do then. File a bug if you want to know more details.

Answer (score -3):

If you need to cache a font, put it in a dictionary with font-name as a key.